# Second-order linear ODE question: $2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} x = 6 \frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given: $$2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} x = 6 \frac{dy}{dx}\\
y(1)=1\\
y(2)=2$$

Find $y$.

I don't know any methods for solving differential equations.

Comment: Are you familiar with separation of variables? Usually this is introduced before a differential equations course is taken.

Comment: No, this is part of a real analysis course and nothing about differential equations was given

Comment: You can change my $y'' = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ back if you wish, but leave the "Second-order Linear ODE question" part as is for search optimisation(and clarity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y'$ is a solution of  $$
xu' = 3u
$$whose general solution is $u(x) = Cx^3$ (found via a separation of variables) so
$$
y(x) = Cx^4 + D\\
C+D = 1\\
16C + D = 2
$$
then, $$
y(x) = \frac 1{15} (x^4 + 14)
$$

Answer (score 2):

So you have $y''x=3y'$ and you want to solve this. First off, note that you can view this as $(y')'x=3y'$ so if you make the replacement $z=y'$ you actually get

$$xz' = 3z.$$

Or

$$z' = \frac{3}{x}z.$$

Refer to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723993/integrating-factor-in-linear-differential-equations/724011#724011) by me a couple of days ago to solve this. Once you get a solution for $z$, you want to then translate this into a solution for $y$. Well since $y' = z$, all you need to do is integrate $z$ to get $y$ and you'll be done.