# Is there any theory surrounding this ability to go back and forth between "logarithms" and "differentiation"?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Given a real number $x>0$, define it's "derivative" as follows:

$$x' = x \log(x).$$

We can easily show that $$(xy)' = x'y+xy'$$ for all $x,y > 0$. In particular: $$(xy)' = xy \log(xy) = xy(\log(x)+\log(y)) = xy \log(x)+xy\log(y) = x'y+xy'$$

So, we started with something, namely logarithms, that turns multiplication into addition, and we obtained something, namely "derivatives" in the above sense, satisfying the Leibniz law, and these are related by $x'/x = \log(x)$.

This suggests that we try to go the other way. Given a function $f$ on the real line, define it's "loogarithm" to be $$\mathrm{loog}(f) = \frac{f'}{f},$$ where $f'$ is the ordinary derivative. If we're willing to assume $f$ is positive, then the loogarithm can be understood as the act of taking the ordinary logarithm and then differentiating. In more detail: $$\mathrm{loog}(f) = (\log(f))'.$$ So basically, $\mathrm{loog}$ is the well-known technique of logarithmic differentiation.

It's straightforward to check that $$\mathrm{loog}(fg) = \mathrm{loog}(f)+\mathrm{loog}(g),$$ which is what makes that technique work, after all.

The above observations generalize readily to derivations on commutative rings/fields.

In particular we're given a function $\log : R \rightarrow R$ on a commutative ring satisfying $\log(xy) = \log(x)+\log(y)$ and $\log(1) = 0$, then we can get a notion of differentiation on $R$ via $x' = x \log(x)$, and it will always satisfy Leibniz. Conversely, the formula $\log(x) = x'/x$ allows us to turn anything satisfying Leibniz into a notion of logarithm that's defined for all units.

> **Question.** Is there any theory surrounding this ability to go back and forth between "logarithms" and "differentiation" in this way? It seems to be rather important.

What follows is a long discussion about this kind of thing.

We might try inverting $\mathrm{loog}$ to get some kind of exponentiation function. Unfortunately, unlike $\log$, the loogarithm is not invertible because differentiation does funny things. Oh well, let's just add the basepoint from which we're going to start integrating as an extra parameter $p$: $$a_p^f := a^{\int_p f}.$$

This exponentiation operator occurs in the method of [integrating factors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html). Some of it's properties are familiar looking:

$$a_p^0 = 1, \qquad a_p^{f+g} = a_p^f a_p^g, \qquad a_p^{-f} = \frac{1}{a_p^f}$$

Others look a bit strange, for example:

$$a^1_p(x) = a^{x-p}$$

And I haven't been able to find anything worthwhile to say about $a_p^{fg}$.

The method of integrating factors works because of the statement:
$$(e_p^f)' = f \cdot e_p^f.$$

That means that we can transform the DE $$f' + pf = q$$ into $$f'e_0^p + pfe_0^p = qe_0^p$$ which becomes $$(f e_0^p)' = qe_0^p.$$ So $$fe_0^p = f(0)+\int_0 qe_0^p$$ which yields $$f = e_0^{-p}\left(f(0)+\int_0 qe_0^p\right)$$

Going back to the idea that numbers can be "differentiated" via $x' = x \log(x)$, the above technique can be applied to solve equations of the form $x \log(x)+px = q.$ In particular, multiply both sides by $e^p$. We obtain:

$$x' e^p + pxe^p = qe^p$$

So $(xe^p)' = qe^p.$

To finish the problem, we can use the Lambert $W$ function and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472996/inverse-of-x-logx-for-x1), or just define our function and call it "integration."

This post is getting pretty long so I might just leave it there.

Comment: I don't think there is much theory. The problem with those definitions is that $(x+y)'\eq x'+y'$. The [arithmetic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative) has the same problem.

Comment: As Professor Vector already remarked, you have that $(x+y)'\neq x'+y'$, which is probably what causes that you cannot find something useful for $a^{fg}_p$.

Comment: @Chappers It seems you forgot to put your question before the question mark. What was it you wanted to know?