# Why this equation is correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am going through the University of Pennsylvania's numerical analysis lectures, which can be found [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DeturckWilf.pdf). I am a bit confused with equation 1.1.9 at page 6-7.

The equation is $y'(x) + a(x)y(x) = b(x)$. The notes say that this can be rewritten as

$$a^{-A(x)}d(a^{A(x)}y(x)) = b(x)$$
 where $A(x)$ is an antiderivative of $a(x)$. So, we have that 
$$y'(x) + a(x)y(x) = a^{-A(x)}d(a^{A(x)}y(x)).$$

Why is that? I can not go from the first equation to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is deceptively anticlimactic, and in one phrase the answer is **the product rule of differentiation**, by which I mean that $(f(x)g(x))' = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$.

> **Claim**:
>
> $$e^{-A(x)}\frac{d}{dx} \left(e^{A(x)}y(x))\right) = y'(x) + a(x)y(x)$$

*Proof:* let's take the derivative on the left.

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( d^{A(x)}y(x)\right) = e^{A(x)}a(x)y(x) + e^{A(x)}y'(x),$$

so that multiplying by $e^{-A(x)}$ gives exactly what we want. $\diamondsuit$

In terms of differential equations, this sort of method is usually called an [integrating factor](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot mixedmath. Very good answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You have not transcribed the notes correctly. The notes say to consider 
$$y'(x) + a(x) y(x) = b(x)$$

Then we rewrite this equation in the equivalent form

$$e^{-A(x)} \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( e^{A(x)} y(x) \right) = b(x)$$

Why is this correct? Because if we apply the derivative operator on the left hand side, we get

$$e^{-A(x)} \left(A'(x) e^{A(x)} y(x) + e^{A(x)} y'(x)  \right) = A'(x)y(x) + y'(x) = b(x)$$

and recall $A'(x) = a(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is called an integrating factor. If we multiply the whole equation by $\exp\left(\int a(x)\,dx\right)$, we get

$$e^{\int a(x)\,dx}y'(x)+a(x)e^{\int a(x)\,dx}y(x) = b(x)e^{\int a(x)\,dx}.$$

Let's consider $\left(e^{\int a(x)\,dx}y(x)\right)'$. By product rule, we get

$$\left(e^{\int a(x)\,dx}\right)'y(x) + e^{\int a(x)\,dx}y'(x).$$

Moreover,

$$\left(e^{\int a(x)\,dx}\right)' = e^{\int a(x)\,dx}\left(\int a(x)\,dx\right)' = a(x)e^{\int a(x)\,dx}.$$

Thus we can realize $\left(e^{\int a(x)\,dx}y(x)\right)'$ as $a(x)e^{\int a(x)\,dx}y(x)+e^{\int a(x)\,dx}y'(x).$ So then our overall expression is

$$\left(e^{\int a(x)\,dx}y(x)\right)' = e^{\int a(x)\,dx}b(x).$$

Multiplying both sides by $e^{-\int a(x)\,dx}$ gives the result. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723993/integrating-factor-in-linear-differential-equations/724011#724011) for a much more detailed exposition on this matter.